# How remove an html elements without the content inside by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How to get this output by jQuery or Javascript:

HTML:

`This is a <span class="getClass" >test</span> for javascript and jquery 
Then suppose <span class="getClass" >it</span>. how can i change it in multiple line
<span class="getClass" >look</span> like this`

Output:

`This is a test for javascript and jquery`

I have tried some code but it does not work, Like:

```
<Script>
        $('.getClass').unwrap();
</script>
```

but it delete the parent element not element itself.

I just have class selector access to the element and want to delete the whole element. I can not read the text inside element.

Thank you.

Comment: Your title says "remove some", but your main body text doesn't mention the "some". Do you mean all tags should be removed?

Comment: sorry i just want to remove the span element arround. i can not get test. I just have access to class name of the element

Comment: OK. So what if the text is:

This is a <span class="getClass" >test<br />another test<br /></span> for javascript and jquery

?

Comment: well, the output must be "This is a test<br />another test<br />for javascript and jquery"

Comment: $('.findedColor').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).html(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agrKZ/1/)**

```
$('.getClass').replaceWith($('.getClass').text());
```

If you do not want to change the DOM but only need to get text without span tags then you can use

```
$('.getClass').text();
```

Comment: well, actually i want exactly look like this, but the issue is that I have multiple 'getClass' with different text.

Comment: $('.findedColor').replaceWith(function()
                        {
                            return $(this).text();
                        });

Comment: So what criteria you have to differentiate elements with class name .getClass?

Comment: $('.findedColor').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).text(); }); Thank you, this one fixed it but now "  " beside the text remain over there that cause another issue for me

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set it to the text content (see [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text))

```
$(containerSelector).text(function (_, text) {
    return text;
});
```

Comment: can you give me script with this html?

Comment: @Danial: It depends what the element is called which the text you've quoted is included in. All you need to do is replace "containerSelector" with a selector to match that element.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want only the text. Using `.text` to get returns the text with all tags stripped automatically. By using `.text` to set the text as well you effectively remove them: http://jsfiddle.net/s4DJP/.

```
$("...").text(function(i, text) {
  return text;
});
```

Comment: can you give me script with this html?

Comment: @Danial: http://jsfiddle.net/s4DJP/3/. Just put it in a container element and have that element its text set.

Answer (score 0):

More generic, use regular expression:

```
$().ready(function(){
var htmlstr = 'This is a <span class="getClass" >test</span> for javascript and jquery';
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var plainstr = htmlstr.replace(new RegExp(regex ), "");
    alert(plainstr );
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qjvxf/4/